# Gitlab Docker Autoscaler executor - Failed to remove network for build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to run gitlab-runner with docker-autoscaler executor. I use fleeting-plugin-aws. I follow this instuctions https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker_autoscaler.html. I've configured Autoscaling Group and it works. But job fails with error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.6.1 (f5da3c5a)
  on autoscaler BN9C-ytN8, system ID: s_bf8d3ace2761
Preparing the "docker-autoscaler" executor
00:10
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://internel.tunnel.invalid/v1.24/info": dialing environment connection: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed) (docker.go:878:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://internel.tunnel.invalid/v1.24/info": dialing environment connection: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed) (docker.go:878:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://internel.tunnel.invalid/v1.24/info": dialing environment connection: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed) (docker.go:878:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): error during connect: Get "http://internel.tunnel.invalid/v1.24/info": dialing environment connection: ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed) (docker.go:878:0s)
```

I've check connection between executor host and instances in ASG. Configured user can establish ssh connection and has permissions to use docker.

## Solution

Upgrade docker to the newest version.

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: After upgrade docker everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the user being used for SSH (in my case `ubuntu` into the docker group, eg:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I've checked even on root account and problem still occurs. I opened an issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/37222